# Android On Orientation Change Crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation, android-orientation

PlaceActivity hosts Two Fragments

1. PlaceDetailsFragment - Which has a view pager - PlaceSlideFragment
2. PlaceMapFramgment - host Google Maps

When i try to change the orientation the app crashes with the following Error Log.

```
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.m7.nomad/com.m7.nomad.PlaceActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.m7.nomad.fragments.PlaceSlideFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3363)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1163)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.m7.nomad.fragments.PlaceSlideFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:405)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1767)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:208)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at com.m7.nomad.PlaceActivity.onCreate(PlaceActivity.java:34)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    ... 12 more
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.m7.nomad.fragments.PlaceSlideFragment; no empty constructor
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
01-12 15:24:57.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30412):    ... 19 more
```

**PlaceSlidesFragemntsAdapter.java**

```
public class PlaceSlidesFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter  {

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(SplashActivity.context);
    List<String> photoList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private int mCount;

    public PlaceSlidesFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        db.open();
        Cursor photosCursor = db.getPhotos(PlaceActivity.placeId);

        // Iterate Through the Place Cursor
        if (photosCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                photoList.add(photosCursor.getString(1));
            } while (photosCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        db.close();

        mCount = photoList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new PlaceSlideFragment(photoList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
            mCount = count;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**PlaceSlideFragment.java**

```
public final class PlaceSlideFragment extends Fragment {
    String imageResourceId;

    public PlaceSlideFragment(String i) {
        imageResourceId = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());

        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(MainActivity.context);
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(imageResourceId, new Activity(), image);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams());

        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(image);

        return layout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Fragment` must have an empty constructor.

Use `setArguments(Bundle)` instead of passing parameters to constructor directly.

In your example in `PlaceSlideFragment.java` remove constructor. Instead, inside `onCreateView` use:

```
imageResourceId = getArguments().getString("param");
```

Then, to instantinate `PlaceSlideFragment` use this code:

```
Fragment f = new PlaceSlideFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("param", yourParam);
f.setArguments(args);
```

or it will be even better if you'll move this code into some static method of `PlaceSlideFragment`

Comment: i am feeding the data to the Viewpager from the database in the constructor.

Comment: You should not do that, use the setArguments method for this

Comment: @HarshaMV use `setArguments` to pass data instead

Comment: have updated my code. can u point out what i am doing wrong. i am not able to understand what changes i have to make

Answer (score 3):

The stacktrace contains the following line

> Unable to instantiate fragment com.m7.nomad.fragments.PlaceSlideFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

There is a problem with the constructor, a good practice with fragments is using a getInstance method that will call the empty constructor.

Why the need of empty constructor?

> Android framework will call these when fragments are recreated e.g.
>   configuration change

If you have any other problems with fragments comment below

EDIT:

FRAGMENT EXAMPLE

```
public final class PlaceSlideFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
      return new PlaceSlideFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(MainActivity.context);
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(getArguments().getInt("key"), new Activity(), image);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams());

        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(image);

        return layout;
    }
}
```

IN PAGER

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        PlaceSlideFragment frag = PlaceSlideFragment.newInstance();
        Bundle args = new Bundle()
        args.putInt("key",ID_RESOURCE_HERE);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }
```

I hope this helps, you can also take a look a retaining fragments and handling configuration changes since you will probably run into other exceptions later on

Comment: have updated my code - can u point out how to make the changes

Comment: Your code will crash with `NullPointerException`. `getArguments` will return `null` if you'll call it from constructor

Comment: i am getting this error The method putArguments(Bundle) is undefined for the type PlaceSlideFragment

Comment: i think it is setArguments

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.m7.nomad.fragments.PlaceSlideFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

This line shows that you doesn't have support library.
Add support library as below:

Right Click Project -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library

and then clean and build your Project.